# Stuck with the "Expected an assignment or function: no-unused expressions"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expression, assignment-operator

I'm really going crazy here and hoping someone can help me with this problem.
I have the following code inside my model:

```
this.text = json.text ? json.text : ''
```

This sends the following warning in my inspector

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

So I tried the following:

```
let text;
if(json.text) text = json.text
else text = ''
this.text = text
```

But this, strangely enough, still returns the same warning.

Can someone give me an explanation as to why this warning presents itself and what I should do to fix this? I would like to have a warning free web app.

Update: 
I cleaned up my code to make it more understandable for those who're not in the project.
These are the two components that react with each other.
For each item I get from my query, I go to the fromJSON method in my model. I push the returned value inside my results array and return that array.

Model.js

```
import BaseModel from './BaseModel'

export default class Model extends BaseModel {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.nis
        this.postal
        this.text
        this.type
    }

    fromJSON(json) {
        this.nis = json.nisCode ? json.nisCode : ''
        this.postal = json.postal ? json.postal : ''
        this.text = json.text ? json.text : ''
        this.type = json.type ? json.type : ''
    }
}
```

Service.js

```
import { BaseService } from './BaseService';
import Model from '../models/Model';
import Translation from '../components/_translations/Meta';

// To get content in correct language
const lang = new Translation().getContent('lang')

export default class Service extends Service {
    async search(keyword, type = 'keyword', query) {
        // Get the results data using the Axios instance
        return this.axiosInstanceOsn.get(query).then(
            value => {
                // First and foremost, check if the call was successful
                if (value.status === 200){

                    const data = value.data
                    let results = []
                    data.forEach(element => {
                        let as = new Model()
                        as.fromJSON(element)
                        results.push(as)
                    })
                    return results
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it perhaps that `this.text` is never used?

Comment: Stop putting "tags" in the titles of your questions - that's what *tags* are for.

Comment: can you please add the more clear code where you initializing the text variable

Comment: I updated my question with the full code of my model and service

Comment: In your model the unused expressions are the pointless `this.nis` etc. in the constructor; according to https://eslint.org/demo the `fromJSON` method is fine. Typically an "alternate constructor" would be provided by a static method, so you don't construct the object in an uninitialised state.

Comment: I understand the eslint explanation and demo. Thank you, I'm going to look further into this.

Comment: You can replace `this.text = json.text ? json.text : ''` with `this.text = json.text || ''`, but I'm not sure whether this will satisfy jslint

Comment: @barbsan jslint is not yet satisfied; thanks for the try though

Comment: @CédricBloem are you sure it complaints about assignments in  `fromJSON` and not about your constructor?

Comment: @barbsan yes, it specifically says that it is about the assaignments inside the fromJSON inside my Model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import BaseModel from './BaseModel'

export default class Model extends BaseModel {
constructor(){
    super()
    this.nis = this.nis || ''
    this.postal = this.postal || ''
    this.text = this.test || ''
    this.type = this.type || ''
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Updated 2**

```
import BaseModel from './BaseModel'

export default class Model extends BaseModel {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.nis = ''
        this.postal = ''
        this.text = ''
        this.type = ''
    }

    fromJSON(json) {
        this.nis = (json.nisCode !== undefined ? json.nisCode : '')
        this.postal = (json.postal !== undefined ? json.postal : '')
        this.text = (json.text !== undefined ? json.text : '')
        this.type = (json.type,!== undefined ? json.type : '')
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly enough my reputation is not high enough to comment directly on the question :(

Comment: Was going to update the answer with a real answer but thanks.

Comment: Also the fromJSON is probably alright but I think it is going to be the constructor. there is no initialization of the variables.

Comment: Good try, but sadly enough this still returns a jslint warning

Comment: Can you try the new answer?

Comment: It still returns the same warning